# Scala parameter type explanation

Tags: scala, playframework

I am pretty new to Scala and Play Framework and I never saw the following parameter type before.

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result)
```

What is confusing me is the `f: =>` part. If that `=>` weren't there I would think of it as a function that maps a `String` to a `Request` and then to a `Result`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, `=> A` is a by name parameter of type A. That means the parameter will only be evaluated if and when (and each time) it is used in the body of the function. Thus, `f` is a by name parameter whose type is a function that takes a `String` and returns a function from a `Request[AnyContent]` to a `Result`. Here is an example of how by name parameter are evaluated:

```
scala> def twice[A](a: =>A) = (a,a)
twice: [A](a: => A)(A, A)

scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> twice {
     |   i += 1
     |   i
     | }
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```